# MySQL Reurn values outside the Where range with a count of 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, part of which looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI2pQ.png)

I want to count for every VideoName the number of Cuepoints which have values between 0 and 60. I am using this query to do so

```
`SELECT VideoName,COUNT(CuePoint) AS min1
    FROM text_xml
    WHERE CuePoint >= 0 and Cuepoint <= 60
    GROUP BY VideoName;`
```

It works for that purpese, however there are videos that do not have Cuepoints in that range. Those videos therefore are not being returned from the query.

My question is how can I make the query return all the videos including the ones that do not have Cuepoints in that range. I want them to be displayed with a count of 0. Something like this min1:'0'.

Comment: `CuePoint >= 0 and Cuepoint <= 60` can be written as `CuePoint between 0 and 60`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT VideoName, SUM(IF(CuePoint >= 0 AND CuePoint <= 60, 1, 0)) AS min1
FROM text_xml
GROUP BY VideoName;`
```

Answer (score 2):

This you can do by moving the `where` condition into a `case when` expression, which you count:

```
SELECT VideoName,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CuePoint >= 0 and Cuepoint <= 60 THEN 1 END) AS min1
FROM text_xml
GROUP BY VideoName;
```

The `count` will count the number of non-null values in the expression. Since the expression yields 1 only for when the condition is true, those will be the ones that are counted. In the other cases, the expression yields `null` which does not increase the count. So for those you will get 0.

Note that this is compliant with standard SQL. MySql will allow a slightly shorter syntax as Gordon has provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by moving the condition to the `SELECT`.  In MySQL, I would do this as:

```
SELECT VideoName, SUM(CuePoint >= 0 and Cuepoint <= 60) AS min1
FROM text_xml
GROUP BY VideoName;
```

MySQL treats a boolean expression as an integer in a numeric context.  "1" is true and "0" is false.  So, this `SUM()` returns the number of rows where the expression evaluates to true.